# Terraform tries to create s3 bucket policy although it exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an AWS S3 bucket previously created with `terraform` named `my-awesome-bucket`.

For some reason out of the scope of this discussion, I added manually the following bucket policy via the AWS console (I am just copying and pasting it here)

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-awesome-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Fast forward to present, where I am just adding the following lines in my corresponding 
s3 resource definition:

```
  policy = <<EOF
  {
      "Version": "2008-10-17",
      "Statement": [
          {
              "Effect": "Deny",
              "Principal": "*",
              "Action": "s3:*",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-awesome-bucket/*",
              "Condition": {
                  "Bool": {
                      "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                  }
              }
          }
      ]
  }
EOF
```

Does anyone have a clue why my `terraform` plan indicates that the policy will be created? (though it **exists**?)

```
$ terraform plan

(...)
  ~ aws_s3_bucket.my-awesome-bucket
      policy: "" => "  {\n      \"Version\": \"2008-10-17\",\n      \"Statement\": [\n          {\n              \"Effect\": \"Deny\",\n              \"Principal\": \"*\",\n              \"Action\": \"s3:*\",\n              \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::my-awesome-bucket/*\",\n              \"Condition\": {\n                  \"Bool\": {\n                      \"aws:SecureTransport\": \"false\"\n                  }\n              }\n          }\n      ]\n  }\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your terraform state doesn't know that the policy already exists. You need to import it first with something like this:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket_policy.example my-bucket-name
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket_policy.html#import

https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/purpose.html

Edit: I reread your question, and it looks like you're using the `policy` argument within an `aws_s3_bucket` resource. The terraform docs say:

> Note that if the policy document is not specific enough (but still
>   valid), Terraform may view the policy as constantly changing in a
>   terraform plan. In this case, please make sure you use the
>   verbose/specific version of the policy.

So you may need to move this policy into its own `aws_s3_bucket_policy` resource and do the import as originally suggested.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html#policy

Comment: thanks. the issue is however I am just copying an pasting the version from the AWS console to the TF script. TF still __fails__ however to view the policy for some reason

Comment: (so the version is right there, both in the TF scripts as in the console and it is exactly the same)

Comment: @pkaramol Right, but it's not in the terraform state. Terraform only knows about things that it has created, or things that have been imported to it. Terraform doesn't inspect all of your cloud resources on each run. It just sees that this policy doesn't exist in its internal state and it wants to create it. Have you tried importing anything?